# Error compiling FTDI VCP drivers: Cannot find version.h

Tags: compiling, kernel-modules, make, c, elementary-os

driver installation fails of [FTDI VCP](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm) driver during `make install`.

Running ElementaryOS with kernel 3.11.0-14-generic

```
make install
awk: cannot open /lib/modules/3.11.0-14-generic/build/include/linux/version.h     (No such file or directory)
awk: cannot open /lib/modules/3.11.0-14-generic/build/include/linux/version.h (No such file or directory)
install -d /lib/modules//misc
install -c ftdi.o /lib/modules//misc
install: cannot stat `ftdi.o': No such file or directory
make install
```

The directory exists and it has multiple files in it but no version.h.

Update: After creating a symbolic link from `uapi` to `modules` as recommended by @slm

`ln -s /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h`
`/lib/modules/linux-($uname -r)/generic/build/include/linux/version.h`

the `awk` errors disappear but the sytem still reports:

```
install -d /lib/modules//misc
install -c ftdi.o /lib/modules//misc
install: cannot stat `ftdi.o': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this mentioned in this OpenSUSE forum, in a post titled: [Thread: Realtek drivers fail to install, missing linux/version.h](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/489429-realtek-drivers-fail-install-missing-linux-version-h.html). The solution offered up in that thread was this:

> With the 3.7 and greter kernel, there was a change to the uapi sources which causes issues with some older drivers which can not locate version.h
>
> You might try:
>
> ```
>    # ln -s /usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h \
>          /usr/src/linux-$(uname -r)/include/linux/
> ```

Comment: I'll definitely try that. One problem, under `/usr/src/` i have `linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic` but not `linux-3.11.0-14-generic` from the `uname -r` output

Comment: i was able to use the headers and link it to the lib/modules directory but now I still get `cannot stat:ftdi.o`

Comment: @BrandonKreisel - please update your Q with this new error message.

Comment: updated as requested

Comment: @BrandonKreisel: Although the system has the kernel headers installed (`linux-headers-3.11.0-14-generic`) it still seems to be missing the kernel sources, which should go under `linux-3.11.0-14-generic`.